# Azure Table Storage Latency

Tags: azure-storage

I am working on a project using Azure Table Storage. I am trying to document the network latency between my webrole and table storage. Does anyone know where I can find some preliminary numbers I could use for estimation?

Thanks
JThomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anecdotally, I expect a latency somewhere between 10 and 30 milliseconds if both the VM and the storage account are in the same data center.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which Gen of Azure Storage your Table entities where created.  Here is information for both:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/11/02/windows-azure-s-flat-network-storage-and-2012-scalability-targets.aspx

It has scalability targets and some network information.  Network latency will be variable, but there are ways to mitigate it: place the web role/table storage in the same data center location.

Comment: Found a copy of the information at a different url: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2012/11/04/cross-post-windows-azures-flat-network-storage-and-2012-scalability-targets/